# Is setting the id of has_one association models equal to user.id in the user model bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the users choose between a role and based on that role I create the appropriate models for them. Would it be considered bad practice to make the id for each model the same id as the user? There is only one unique integer for each user and they are all has_one relationships with no destroy actions.

Will this lead to any type of problem in the future for the database?

**user.rb**

```
has_one :companyinfo, dependent: :destroy
has_one :social, dependent: :destroy
has_one :summary, dependent: :destroy
has_one :contact, dependent: :destroy

after_create :add_companyinfo
after_create :add_social
after_create :add_contact
after_create :add_summary


def add_companyinfo
    if self.role == "startup"
        Companyinfo.create(user: self, id: self.id, company_name: self.name)
    end
end

def add_social
  if self.role == "startup"
    Social.create(user: self, id: self.id)
  end
end

def add_contact
  if self.role == "startup"
    Contact.create(user: self, id: self.id)
  end
end

def add_summary
  if self.role == "startup"
    Summary.create(user: self, id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: why do you need to explictly set the id of each model, you can get the associated model to that user by doing `user.contact` for any resource

Comment: Yes, it is a bad practice. You are not expected to manually assign auto-incremented IDs when the framework and the DB are trying to bear that burden for you. Why fight the framework?

Comment: And, before everything, what is the win from doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a bad practice.

You should not set the id of a record by yourself.

The `id` field is a protected attribute, and its default protected for a reason.

With your associations all you need to do is set the user on the models, and then you can get the user like that:

```
company_info = CompanyInfo.first
company_info.user # will return the user associated with that company_info record

social = Social.first
social.user # will return the user associated with that social record

contact = Contact.first
contact.user # will return the user associated with that contact record

summary = Summary.first
summary.user # will return the user associated with that summary record
```

and on the other way you can get any associated model like so:

```
user = User.first
user.company_info # will return the associated CompanyInfo record
user.social # will return the associated Social record
user.contact # will return the associated Contact record
user.summary # will return the associated Summary record
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!